# I keep getting this error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to figure out how to work through Jupyter Notebook and for one of the exercises I did this. However after I run it I keep getting an error. Any suggestions as to what might be the issue?

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import collections

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparKContent/ml-100k/u.data")
ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
result = ratings.countByValue()

sortedResults = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(result.items()))
for key, value in sortedResults.items():
print("%s %i" % (key, value))
```

[image: Error message]

[image: error message cont.]

Comment: Error says `Input path does not exist`. Here's my suggestion - check the path, this might be the issue.

Comment: you are using Windows right? so where is the drive of the input path? I mean the input path has to look similar like this `file:///C:/YOUR_FILE_PATH`